# "An unknown FastCGI error ocurred" using FastCGI with Django on Windows Server

Tags: python, django, windows, iis, fastcgi

I am trying to run a Django application on a Windows Server VM hosted on Microsoft Azure. I'm using Python 3.6.

I already made all the configurations in this Microsoft tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/classic/python-django-web-app), but I still get an error message:

> "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error" "An unknown FastCGI error
>   occurred"

here's my web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
     <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()" />
     <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tb_product" />
     <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="tb_project.tb_project.settings" />
   </appSettings>
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
         <add name="Python FastCGI" 
              path="*" 
              verb="*" 
              modules="FastCgiModule"
              scriptProcessor="c:\users\giorgecaique\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe|c:\users\giorgecaique\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
              resourceType="Unspecified"
              requireAccess="Script" />
     </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Can anyone help me?

Cheers!

Comment: It's been a while, can you tell us how did you solve this error.

Comment: @Giorge Caique Did you managed to find the solution?